# Alignment Error When Using Stacked Bars

Tags: graph, spotfire, tibco, stacked-chart

I'm using a Stacked bars visualisation on one of my Spotfire pages, but whatever the reason, the bars start to get misaligned with the axis as can be seen on the attached image:
[image: Misaligned event]

The event *Start Time* is 125.45, but is been shown after 125.5.

A couple of other images to show it better.

This one, it looks like the value (blue box) is correct (237.7 right before 238).
[image: Correct]

The green box, which is right on top of the previous, has the same 237.7 value but is after 238. How can that be?

[image: Wrong]

Any idea of how to fix that?

Comment: this is interesting... can you expand the screenshot area without comprimising anything? it may be a bug with Spotfire. are you sure the preceeding bar segments add up expectedly?

Comment: Hi @niko. Thanks for your comment. Has just added a couple more images to show the error.

Answer (score 1):

without looking at your entire analysis, it's a bit of a guessing game. my gut tells me that your label expression generating the 125.45 is probably not the same as your X Axis expression, or that your Color By expression is providing you unexpected results. I would look at the preceeding segments on that bar and try to determine why they aren't adding up correctly.

Spotfire wouldn't tell you that the start point is at 140 instead of 125 unless there is some reason to. that it doesn't match the tooltip label is indicative of a different expression.